# Do the number of choices in a A/B test affect sample size needed for statistical significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, ab-test

I apologize if I sound too stupid, but my statistics knowledge is very basic.

I'm a software engineer and I'm conducting an experiment over web page conversions in which I'm trying to determine the best "link text" among multiple alternatives.

I present one of the link text alternatives to each user that visits the page and record which one gets clicked most often.

Given I can have N alternatives, how can I calculate the sample size needed to elect a "winner" among these, given I need 95% of confidence to do that?

So, an example scenario would be:

- 1000 users
- 5 alternatives
- Results:

  - Alternative 1: 39 clicks
  - Alternative 2: 20 clicks
  - Alternative 3: 14 clicks
  - Alternative 4: 13 clicks
  - Alternative 5: 27 clicks

In this scenario, Alternative 1 is ahead up to now, but how sure can I be that it is in fact the winner? How many more users do I need to be sure? Do the number of alternatives affect the result?